# While deploying my smart contract in my deploy.js file showing error due to throwing inside of an async function without a catch block

Tags: javascript, async-await, deployment, ethereum

I am deploying my smart contract of Ethereum blockchain in deploy.js showing error [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#".] {
code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

My code is as below:

```
const HDWalletProvider=require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')
const Web3=require('web3')
const {interface,bytecode}=require('./compile')

const provider=new HDWalletProvider(
    'MY SECRET KEY',
    'https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/UVud9ZoAdGEt747J95NyOyUsS4bre3Oe'
);
const web3=new Web3(provider);

const deploy =async ()=>{
    const accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from Account',accounts[0]);
    const result= await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy ({data:bytecode})
        .send({gas:'1000000', from:accounts[0]});

        console.log(result);
        
};
deploy();
```

deploy.js file is not deploying my contract due to some catch() error.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy is an async function here, which means it involves a promise.

So you need to use the then/catch syntax in order to make it work correctly.

try `deploy().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

This should either log whatever the function deploy returns or the error you get.
You can also catch inside of the function

```
const deploy = async () => {
  try {
    const accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from Account',accounts[0]);
    const result= await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy ({data:bytecode})
        .send({gas:'1000000', from:accounts[0]});

        console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }     
};
```